# Derivative of $\int_0^x F(x, t) dt$

Tags: calculus

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to express the integral $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^x F(x, t) dt$$ in other useful terms?

So I would like a method that expresses this in terms of single-variable integrals, i.e. integrals of the form $\int_a^b G(t)dt$.

For example, I have the integral

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^x - \frac{\text{cos}(xt)}{t} dt $$

I think this should be very elementary, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: The integral isn’t well defined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^xF(x,t) dt = \int_0^x \frac{ \partial}{\partial x} F(x,t) dt + F(x,x)$$

Answer (score 0):

By the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int^x_0-\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}dt & =-\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+ \int^x_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(-\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}\right)dt \\
&= -\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+ \int^x_0 \sin(xt)\, dt \\
&= -\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}- \frac{\cos(x^2)}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\\
&= -\frac{2\cos(x^2)}{x}+\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}